# No way to insert <tab/> in Flex RichEditableText flowlayout

Tags: apache-flex, tabs, richeditabletext

I have some issue with this code :

```
<s:RichEditableText id="ta" width="100%" height="200" selectable="true" editable="true"/>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
var str:String = "some text<tab/>with tab";
ta.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(str, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT);
]]>
</fx:Script>
```

When running the text is show without space :

"some textwith tab"

---

#### Solved

I finaly find the solution:

```
var config:Configuration = Configuration(ta.textFlow.configuration);
var format:TextLayoutFormat = new TextLayoutFormat();
format.whiteSpaceCollapse = WhiteSpaceCollapse.PRESERVE;
config.textFlowInitialFormat = format;
ta.textFlow = TextConverter.importToFlow(str, TextConverter.TEXT_FIELD_HTML_FORMAT,config);
```

Comment: You can post an answer to your question (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Flex's "text field HTML format" only supports a [subset](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d52.html#WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7d48) of HTML tags:

```
anchor <a>
bold <b>
break <br>
font <font>
image <img>
italic <i>
list item <li>
paragraph <p>
text format <textformat>
```

You should get better results if you replace `<tab />` with `/t` in your sample string.